# A plague spreading on a graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

This is a problem I heard from a friend. I didn't figure it out, so I want to post it here because it's quite an interesting problem.

> The island pictured below is made up of nine towns. One day, a plague arrives at $G$. Though the citizens do their best to contain the plague, each road between an infected and uninfected village has a $10\%$ chance every day to spread it to the uninfected one. How long do we expect it to take until the whole population is infected?"

[image]

**My attempt:**

Probability is not my strong suit, so I couldn't get very far with this problem. The naive way to go about it is to build a probability tree, but I feel like there has to be a simpler way to do with the degrees of the vertices. The problem I keep running into, though, is that you can easily calculate probabilities for the first day - 10% to each neighboring town, 20% overall, but past that you have too many possible infection maps to do any meaningful calculations.

I also just noticed that the last node to be infected (in terms of probability) will be the farthest from $G$, which is $A$ - 4 edges away. Because each day there is a 10% chance of one of those edges being infected, we have an average time of $10*4$=40 days to get to $A$. Is this a correct solution?

If not, what is the solution to this problem?

**EDIT:** The answers posted thus far have been amazing, but this problem was given to mathematically talented high school students so there has to be a simple solution (in terms of math used, not the argument itself). I'll be offering a bounty for such an answer when it's available.

Comment: numerically it is straightforward, but analytically it's harder; here is a similar question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22443/what-is-the-probability-of-a-virus-spreading-through-a-network-given-a-virus-sou

Comment: You might be able to solve using that idea, but it's not quite so simple.  The expected waiting time until A is infected is 10 + the expected waiting time until B is infected which is 10 + the expected waiting time until E is infected.  But E has several possible sources of infection, so calculating the expected waiting time until E is infected is not so easy.  Also, it's not clear to me that if we know the expected waiting time for each town, we know the expected waiting time for all towns.

Comment: Of course it can be modeled as an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) but as you say, there are lots of states.  (512 a priori, though not all of them are possible.)

Comment: I don't think it's likely that there's a simpler way to do this, although you can reduce the scale considerably.  In the given problem, every state must include A, which cuts the number of states in half.  Also, the graph consisting of the infected towns and the edges between them must be connected.  This surely reduces the number of states considerably again.  Still, I'll bet there are more states than it's convenient to work with by hand.  I'll work out the number and let you know.

Comment: There are 51 reachable states.  You can run the script I added to my answer if you want to know what they are, but this is still far too many for manual computation.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the graph has a lot of symmetry: the two four-cycles $(EDGH)$ and $(ECFI)$ can be exchanged. From that you can say the expected times from $G$ and $F$ must be equal, and likewise $H$ and $I$, and $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 5):

As been already mentioned here, one way to approach this problem is through Markov Chains. Given that solution heavily relies on connectivity graph, I doubt it is possible to get a closed form.

For your particular setup, you have a Markov Chain with $2^9 = 512$ states, each state might also be represented by a vector of $9$ numbers, being $1$ if corresponding town is infected and $0$ otherwise, also this vectors for convenience can be enumerated as decimals $0 - 511$.

Then you will have to build transition matrix, which is based on connectivity graph. I'll give an example on simplified version with $4$ towns, where $A \ \rightarrow \{B\}$, $B \rightarrow \{A, C, D\}$, $C \rightarrow \{B, D\}$, $D \rightarrow \{B, C\}$. Suppose you have state $\{0, 1, 1, 0\}$. Possible transitions from it are to:

- {1, 1, 1, 0} - plague travels from $B$ to $A$, with probability $0.081$;
- {0, 1, 1, 1} - plague travels from $B$ to $D$ or from $C$ to $D$, with probability $0.171$;
- {1, 1, 1, 1} - both $A$ and $D$ get infested, probability $0.019$;
- {0, 1, 1, 0} - no new infestations, probability $0.729$.

Having completed this for all possible $512$ states (obviously, states $\{0, 0, \ldots, 0\}$ and $\{1, 1, \ldots, 1\}$ are absorbing), you'll get transition matrix $M$, where $M[S_0, S_1]$ is transition probability from state $S_0$ to $S_1$.

After that, if $T \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is the day when last town(s) get infested, $M^T[S_0, \{1, 1, \ldots, 1\}]$ gives you probability distribution of time $T$. $M^T$ is matrix $M$ multiplied by itself $T - 1$ times, and $S_0$ is your starting state. For any finite $T$ you'll have $M^T[S_0, \{1, 1, \ldots, 1\}] < 1$, but it converges to one fairly quickly.

I actually got interested and took some time to code this in Python. After $500$ days $M^{499}[S_0, \{1, 1, \ldots, 1\} > 1 - 10^{-15}$, pretty much enough, I would say. I got $E[T] \approx 34.554$ days, and probability density graph below. After $79$ days all towns would be infested with probability $> 0.99$.

[image: Probability distribution f(T)]

Interestingly enough, starting plague in the most remove town $A$ doesn't help much - $E[T]$ becomes $38.038$ days, only little more than $3$ extra days on average. On the other hand, if plague start in central town $E$, $E[T]$ becomes $24.814$ days, and $64$ days is enough to get all towns infested with probability $> 0.99$.

**ADDITION:** I've corrected the example on calculating transition probabilities and results and run simulations to check them. Based on $200000$ rounds for each case, I've got $E[T] = 34.539$ days when plague starts in $G$, and $E[T] = 38.063$ days when plague starts in $A$.

Comment: Thank for the very thorough answer! How hard this problem is to crack is surprising - it was a problem given to high school students! No idea how well they did, though.

Comment: Well, that must have been one very advanced high school. I actually found a mistake in my calculations, was a bit off with transition probabilities. I updated the example case, but it is already late here, so I'll update calculation results later. They changed a little.

Comment: I'm getting a very different result with simulation.  Please look at my answer and tell me if you see a mistake.

Comment: I wrote a script using Markov chains and it produced a value that agrees with my simulations very closely, so I think there's a mistake in your computations.  I updated my answer to include the latest script.  The only mistake I can think that I might have made is in the definition of the graph, since it's the same in both scripts, but if there's a mistake, I can't find it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there was a mistake in my calculation of transition probabilities in cases when not all towns out of possible ones get infested during single day. I updated my post and also ran simulations (200000 rounds) for both cases when plague starts in A and in G - got results very close to yours.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring :-).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach this, more accessible to high school students than Markov chains, is through simulation.  Rather than try to solve the problem exactly, simulate the spread of infection many times on a computer and calculate the average time to infect all towns.  Here's a little python script that does this.

```
import random
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = 'A B C D E F G H I'.split()
edges = {a:{b},b:{a,e},c:{e,f},d:{e,g},e:{b,c,d,h,i},
         f:{c,i},g:{d,h},h:{e,g,i},i:{e,f,h}}
for x,y in edges.items():
     for z in y: assert x in edges[z]
random.seed()
universe={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}
trials = 1000
average = 0 
for _ in range(trials):
     infected = {a}
     days = 0
     while infected != universe:
          days += 1
          roads = {(town,x) for town in infected for x in edges[town]}
          for road in roads:
               if random.random()<.1:
                    infected.add(road[1])
     average += days
print(average/trials)
```

I ran this once and got $37.927.$  There are several possible improvements.  First, run more than $1000$ trials.  Second, make a histogram of the results, instead of just computing the average.  Third, you can compute the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error), to compute a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for your estimate.

Since the size of the transition matrix grows exponentially with the number of towns, I would guess that if anything like this is really done in epidemiology, it is more likely done with simulation than Markov chains, although I'm sure the simulation would be much more sophisticated than this.

**EDIT**

With 100,000 trials, I consistently get an average of $38$, very different from fanvacoolt's answer. I can't see any mistake in my code, so I'm going to have to try the Markov chain approach -- but not tonight.

**EDIT**
I wrote a script to compute the expected number of days until all towns are infected, using Markov chains and the [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps).  It produced a result in perfect agreement with the simulations, so it must be correct.  Here's the script:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import chain

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = 'A B C D E F G H I'.split()
edges = {a:{b},b:{a,e},c:{e,f},d:{e,g},e:{b,c,d,h,i},
         f:{c,i},g: {d,h},h:{e,g,i},i:{e,f,h}}
universe={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}
for x,y in edges.items():
    for z in y: assert x in edges[z]
weight={a:1,b:2,c:4,d:8,e:16,f:32,g:64,h:128,i:256}

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = set(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def index(s):
    "convert a set of towns to an array index"
    return sum(weight[town] for town in s)

def transitionMatrix():
    "construct and return the trnsition matrix"
    P=np.zeros((512,512)) # transition matrix
    for old in powerset(universe):
        idx = index(old)
        roads = {(town,x)  for town in old for x in edges[town] if x not in old}
        r = len(roads)
        for t in powerset(roads):
            k=len(t)
            prob = .1**k*.9**(r-k)
            spread = {x[1] for x in t}
            new = set(old) | set(spread)
            jdx=index(new)
            P[idx, jdx] += prob
    return P

P = transitionMatrix()
Q= P[1:511,1:511]  # transitions between transient states
del(P)
N = np.linalg.inv(np.eye(510)-Q)  #fundamental matrix
N=N@np.ones((510))

def steps(s):
    "Average number of days until all twons infected starting from set s"
    return N[index(s)-1]  # row 0 was deleted from transition matrix

print(steps({'A'}))
```

Running this produces `38.0376337969`.  Even with only $1000$ trials, the simulation script consistently produces values close to $38$.

**ONE LAST THING**

If we consider only the states that are actually reachable starting with only town A infected, there are 51 states.  Here is a python script that computes them.

```
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import chain

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = 'A B C D E F G H I'.split()
edges = {a:{b},b:{a,e},c:{e,f},d:{e,g},e:{b,c,d,h,i},
              f:{c,i},g:{d,h},h:{e,g,i},i:{e,f,h}}
universe={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = set(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def possible(s):
    '''
    s is a possible state if it includes A and the induced subgraph is connected
    '''
    if a not in s: return False
    Q = {a}
    visited = set()
    while Q:
        x = Q.pop()
        visited.add(x)
        for y in edges[x]:
            if y in s and y not in visited:
                Q.add(y)
    return len(s)==len(visited)

possibilities = []
for s in powerset(universe):
    if possible(s): possibilities.append(s)

print(len(possibilities))
for p in possibilities:print(''.join(sorted(p)))
```